# Message: Element <input class="file-drag-target _ngcontent-tkc-69" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, selenium

Hey guys looking for a bit of guidance on this. I am trying to use a selenium request to upload a file using selenium. I have tested in the console whether the element is available and is clickable through selenium. However I am trying to upload a file. I can see the element no problem and can click on it so the other answers of setting the height, making the element to visible and focusing on it that I have found on stack are not relevant here nut I tried it anyway and I still get the same error.

```
elem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type=file]")
js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; 
arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'  arguments[0].focus();"

browser.execute_script(js, elem)
```

I have also tried moving to the element

```
action.move_to_element(elem)
```

The error is telling me the element is not reachable by keyboard. I have also tried setting the focus to the element and no luck. Wondering could someone provide some guidance on this? Thanks very much

```
upload = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=file]")
upload.send_keys("/test/")
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test

Comment: Not it is not.... please read my comments I have tried this. the send key function does not work correctly for me.

Comment: Is your input disabled?

Comment: No but looking through I find the element says it is not displayed but I can see it visibly on screen and can easily target it in console.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the fact that you are taking an element that was never intended to be visible and forcing it to be visible to interact with it. Don't do that... instead interact with the page as a regular user would. Surely whatever you are wanting to do a regular user can do... automate those steps instead.

Comment: Hi guys,

So I got it working. The issue was a bunch of overlays on the page and selenium not focusing on the current visible one in the ui. I got it working by moving the elements I wanted to interact with to another parent (the body) and removing the overlay element.

Note this works for me as I am not testing anything and do not own the website but instead automating a task to upload files and I would not recommend this approach for testing or production where api's are available. Thanks for the help